# Unable to create dynamic link "An error occurred when creating a new Dynamic Link"

Tags: email, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, whitelist

I'm trying to add passwordless email signin to my Firebase app, so the first thing I did was to whitelist my domain:

[image: whitelisted domain]

Next, I tried to create the dynamic link:

[image]
[image]
[image]

At this point, when I pressed the **Create** button, I got the error. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried what was suggested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY) with the same result.

One last thing and then I've run out of ideas: In the Chrome developer console, I see the Create is failing with an error 400, suggesting that I needed to update the whitelisted URLs. I did that by adding the following URL:

[image]

and also [image]

This problem has been driving me crazy. I've tried everything, I think. Makes me wonder if I need to recreate my app in Firebase.

Comment: did it fix your issue or are you still having it cz i found another fix

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This issue usually means that your pattern doesn't match with your deep link URL.

So if you're trying to add https://pento-2a27b.firebaseapp.com as your deep link, you should have a whitelist pattern similar to `^https://pento-2a27b\.firebaseapp\.com`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Holy S**T! It worked!! Thanks a whole bunch. Now the only question is, how do I award you the 50 point bounty, since the bounty period expired?

Comment: that's something I cannot answer. I'm so sorry.. >.< I'm here to help fellow developers and I'm more than happy enough to know that my suggested whitelist pattern worked for you.

Comment: Maybe you can upvote it yourself and at least get half credit. I tried to log in with different accounts but SO knew it was me, so I could only give one upvote.

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot upvote your own posts/answer. maybe tag someone you knew here who works in Firebase so it gets upvoted. lol

Comment: @dev.for.fun You have also just totally made my night by rescuing me from 2 hours of complete hell! Hence the upvotes on your answer and comments! You really do deserve the bounty that the OP was trying to give you; what a shame that you saw this question too late :-(

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth only supports custom Firebase Dynamic Links without custom paths.

So if your custom domain is https://example.com/link, it won't work. However, configuring https://example.com as the custom domain will work.
Therefore im thinking the issue is with the URL you are providing

Also take a look at this , it also displays how to create URL .
[Firebase says "Domain not whitelisted" for a link that is whitelisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374411/firebase-says-domain-not-whitelisted-for-a-link-that-is-whitelisted)

Give me a response of your outcome :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Anjula, but setting the dynamic link to https://www.example.com didn't help; in fact, I had tried that earlier. As for the suggestion about whitelisting, I had already whitelisted the link.

Comment: @FractalBob I think i may have found your issue , i think it is still the pattern that confuses the link to be recognized as not whitelisted.  Take a look at this ,    https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429?hl=en  make sure you use the same patter for both of them

Comment: Thanks again. I tried changing the whitelisted item to ^https://pentoapp\.page\.link/.*$ but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create** Firebase dynamic link **domain** using **app.page.link**
2. Get Your **link** of which you want to create dynamic link, **get string pattern from Url regexator**
3. Go to setting in Firebase Dynamic Link. **Add linkRegexator in whitelist pattern**
4. Create New Dynamic Link in with campaign